# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp-web/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

i have a problem with my web application that i created with eclipse.

[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-4) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp-web/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'

I don't know how can i resolve it.

This is my web.xml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

This is the pom.xml of web side:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.lino</groupId>
      <artifactId>myapp-web</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <name>myapp-web</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lino</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet Spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>      
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>myapp-web</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

The controller is this:

```
    package com.lino.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import com.lino.dao.ContactDAO;
import com.lino.bean.Contact;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private ContactDAO contactDAO;

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
    List<Contact> listContact = contactDAO.list();
    model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
    model.setViewName("home");

    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
    Contact newContact = new Contact();
    model.addObject("contact", newContact);
    model.setViewName("ContactForm");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
    contactDAO.saveOrUpdate(contact);       
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
    int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    contactDAO.delete(contactId);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
    int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    Contact contact = contactDAO.get(contactId);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
    model.addObject("contact", contact);

    return model;
}
```

}

[The structure in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GBGl.png)

It returns a 404 error.

Thank you.

Comment: Where's the servlet.xml?

Comment: where is your `contextConfigLocation` param ?

Comment: @chaoluo i forgot to write contextConfigLocation param.
Thank you for your response.